# MPI Program Floating-point exception Fortran

Tags: parallel-processing, fortran, mpi

I need to write a program, which sends a particular column to another process.
I try a simple algorithm with two processes, but mpi gives me floating point exception in send or recv ( can't figure where). Why does it happen?

```
program main

implicit none
include 'mpif.h'
integer  :: myid, nprocs, isend,ierr,i,nx, j, status
INTEGER ,dimension(:,:), allocatable:: u 

call MPI_INIT(ierr)
call MPI_COMM_RANK(MPI_COMM_WORLD, myid, ierr)
call MPI_COMM_SIZE(MPI_COMM_WORLD, nprocs, ierr)

nx = 1

if (myid .eq. 0) then
    allocate(u(0:nx,myid*2/nprocs:(myid+1)*2/nprocs))
else
    allocate(u(0:nx,myid*2/nprocs-1:(myid+1)*2/nprocs-1))
end if

u(:,:)=myid+1

call MPI_BARRIER(MPI_COMM_WORLD,ierr )

if (myid .eq. 0) then
    isend = nx+1
    CALL MPI_SEND(u(:,int((myid+1)*2/nprocs-1)),isend,MPI_INT ,myid+1,1,MPI_COMM_WORLD,ierr)
    CALL MPI_RECV(u(:,int((myid+1)*2/nprocs)),isend,MPI_INT ,myid+1,1,MPI_COMM_WORLD,status,ierr)
else
    isend = nx+1
    CALL MPI_RECV(u(:,int((myid)*2/nprocs-1)),isend,MPI_INT ,myid-1,1,MPI_COMM_WORLD,status,ierr)
    CALL MPI_SEND(u(:,int((myid)*2/nprocs)),isend,MPI_INT ,myid-1,1,MPI_COMM_WORLD,ierr)
END IF
call MPI_BARRIER(MPI_COMM_WORLD,ierr )
call MPI_FINALIZE(ierr)
end
```

error:

```
Program received signal SIGFPE: Floating-point exception - erroneous arithmetic operation.
unable to read the cmd header on the pmi context, Error = -1
```

Comment: I don't immediately see the  source of the error you report, but I see something which is often the source of errors in MPI programs.  Replace `include 'mpif.h'` with `use mpi` and adjust your compilation process accordingly.  By using the module you enable the compiler to check, at compile time, that the arguments supplied to `mpi` routines are correct in kind, type and dimension.

Comment: The issue involves `status`.

Comment: Indeed - status is an array, and a Use mpi might have caught that. Include 'mpif.h' is something of the 1990s and shouldn't be used today

Comment: @IanBush Unfortunately, the official OpenMPI documentation was showing this as the default in the examples even in 2018. But anyway, I was hit by this error in the must myself even when I *did* use the mpi module. And not just in 2012, even mor recently.

Comment: @High Performance Mark  
Thanks a lot, use mpi solves the problem

Comment: @vladimir-f can you please point me to the official Open MPI documentation ? fwiw, the man pages were updated with `USE MPI ! or the older form: INCLUDE 'mpif.h'`. And if your Fortran compiler supports (necessary bits of) Fortran 2008, you also get the new and better `use mpi_f08` syntax.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet The man pages of v.2, still the default on many (super-)computers, even those well maintained ones, and still supported now, so certainly suported in 2018. In fact I just tried to google man MPI_Barrier and the result I got was v2.

Comment: @VladimirF thanks ! I will have these unindexed since v2 is no more supported.